# How to load & use column names/headers > 65 char in IICS?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

CSV/ Flat file with column names with no. of months and dates E.g. Benchmark Bloomberg 6 months in year 10/30/2018..
Informatica( IICS) fails to load > 65 char field names, so I loaded it as data -first row. Now I need to do unpivot and do logic based on the “original column Names” i.e. if the month was 6 & date was Oct 30 2018 compare with created date and do X. My best approach is as below. Please suggest a better approach.
1) load column names also as data 2) take out row 1 and store it as 1 row table 3) unpivot the table to make 1 column table and re-pivot it to make column names 4) Apply to the original table in SQL( no issues with > 65 char)

Answer (score 0):

If your fields will always be in the same sequence edit the header names in the source transformation. Configure the source so that data starts on second row. There may be an option to ignore header row values. It should be clear from the UI once you edit the transformation.

Comment: Thanks,Scott. The sequence can change & even more columns will be added every quarter. Also, once the col headers are in first row & data in 2nd row, I can totally filter the first row out but then I lose the header info. I don’t want to lose it; I just want to rename(shorten colmn names) & put it back where they were.

Comment: I have you python scripts in the past to handle formatting the source file in a pre processing script. Use parameters to manage it dynamically from the mapping configuration.

Comment: Ok let me try using python scripts in pre-processing command in mapping task and then parameter files to keep the mapping dynamics- Thanks!